# Communication between 2 Mac computers with Erlang

Tags: erlang

I followed the book "Programming Erlang — Joe Armstrong" to try to build the communication between 2 Mac computers with Erlang (Chap 14):

```erlang
% file: kvs.erl
-module(kvs).
-export([start/0, store/2, lookup/1]).

start() -> register(kvs, spawn(fun() -> loop() end)).

store(Key, Value) -> rpc({store, Key, Value}).
lookup(Key) -> rpc({lookup, Key}).

rpc(Q) ->
  kvs ! {self(), Q},
  receive
    {kvs, Reply} ->
      Reply
  end.

loop() ->
  receive
    {From, {store, Key, Value}} ->
      put(Key, {ok, Value}),
      From ! {kvs, true},
      loop();
    {From, {lookup, Key}} ->
      From ! {kvs, get(Key)},
      loop()
  end.
```

Set up **Mac 1 (Mac Pro) and run a Erlang server:**

```
$ sudo hostname this.is.macpro.com
$ hostname
this.is.macpro.com

$ ipconfig getifaddr en2
aaa.bbb.ccc.209

$ erl -name server -setcookie abcxyz
(server@this.is.macpro.com)> c("kvs.erl").
{ok,kvs}
(server@this.is.macpro.com)> kvs:start().
true
(server@this.is.macpro.com)> kvs:store(hello, world).
true
(server@this.is.macpro.com)> kvs:lookup(hello).
{ok,world}
```

I tried using both IP and hostname to make a RPC from another Mac but get `{badrpc, nodedown}`.

Set up **Mac 2 (MacBook Pro)** and try to call Mac 1:

```
$ sudo hostname this.is.macbookpro.com
$ hostname
this.is.macbookpro.com

$ ipconfig getifaddr en2
aaa.bbb.ccc.211   # different IP

$ erl -name client -setcookie abcxyz
% try using the hostname of Mac 1 but failed
(client@this.is.macbookpro.com)> rpc:call('server@this.is.macpro.com', kvs, lookup, [hello]).
{badrpc, nodedown}

% try using the IP address of Mac 1 but failed
(client@this.is.macbookpro.com)> rpc:call('server@aaa.bbb.ccc.209', kvs, lookup, [hello]).  
{badrpc, nodedown}
```

How to set up my Mac computers and make them available for RCP with Erlang?

Answer (score 1):

When using th `-name`, you should provide the full name. The syntax you are using is for `-sname`. Try this:

```
erl -name server@this.is.macpro.com -setcookie "abcxyz"

erl -name client@this.is.macbookpro.com -setcookie "abcxyz"
```

You can also specify the an IP after the `@` in both cases.

Then from one node, connect to the other node:

```
net_kernel:connect_node('client@this.is.macbookpro.com').
```

This should return `true`. If it returns false then you are not connected. You can very with `nodes().`.

```
(joe@teves-MacBook-Pro.local)3> net_kernel:connect_node('steve@Steves-MacBook-Pro.local').
true
(joe@teves-MacBook-Pro.local)4> nodes().
['steve@Steves-MacBook-Pro.local']
```

If this does not fix it, then you can check `epmd` on both systems to ensure they are registered.

```
epmd -names
```